# Read all phone contacts and update them. windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, contacts

I want to get all contacts stored in phone and update them as per requirement.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-8-Contacts-Integration.aspx

This link shows to get contacts but I'm not getting all contacts. I'm only getting contacts that have been created using my app.

Is there any way I can get all contacts and change mobile numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From the link you provided (emphasis added):

> With Windows Phone 8, Microsoft introduces a new concept of "custom
>   contact stores" [2]. In addition to the read-only access to the user's
>   contact list and the above demonstrated way to use a separate task for
>   creating new entries (both of which available in 7.x) we now are able
>   to write our own data to the people hub silently and without user
>   consent. **However apps still cannot manipulate existing contacts that
>   originate from somewhere else**. In this sense, the data that belongs to
>   an app is somewhat isolated from the rest.

This is by design, you can't edit contacts you didn't create.

Comment: thanks. But I knew it was written in. I post in hope that I may get any solution.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
void GetContact()
{
    cons = new Contacts();
    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(ContactsSearchCompleted);
    //Start the asynchronous search.
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

private void ContactsSearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    cons.SearchCompleted -= ContactsSearchCompleted;
    //e.Results should be the list of contact, since there's no filter applyed in the search you shoul have all contact here
}
```

not this is a copy paste of an old not tested code of mine so you might have to change something

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've tried this method. It gives me all contacts but how can I update If I want to?

Answer (score 0):

You cant' - stupid crappy MS don't even support contact import from vcard file. ALL MS want that you put every your data to their servers so they own it.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should at Contact `Capability`

**for wp8** add from **WMAppManifest.xml**

[image]

**for wp8.1** add from **Package.appxmanifest**

[image]

Now define a class `PhoneContact` to store the data

```
public class PhoneContact {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Create a ObservableCollection and Call the following action from constructor to read the contact list. **N.B** use the following namespace also

```
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

ObservableCollection<PhoneContact> phoneContact;
public MainPage() {
     InitializeComponent();
     phoneContact = new ObservableCollection<PhoneContact>();
     ReadPhoneContact();
}

void ReadPhoneContact(){
     Contacts cnt = new Contacts();
     cnt.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);
     cnt.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}
```

After reading all contact fire the following event. you can read multiple contact number, email etc.

```
void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
   foreach (var item in e.Results) {
      var contact = new PhoneContact();
      contact.Name = item.DisplayName;
      foreach (var pn in item.PhoneNumbers)
          contact.Number = string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Number) ? pn.PhoneNumber : (contact.Number + " , " + pn.PhoneNumber);
      foreach (var ea in item.EmailAddresses)
           contact.Email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Email) ? ea.EmailAddress : (contact.Email + " , " + ea.EmailAddress);
      phoneContact.Add(contact);
   }  
}
```